# Manipulating csv files from long format using numpy or pandas

Tags: python, csv, file-io, numpy, pandas

I am trying to write a simple script to convert a csv output file from a Fortran code into an Pandas DataFrame object so I can do more analysis. The csv has two columns but consists of multiple appended blocks of data with the shape [n,2] (each sample name has the format RN_x).  I got as far as the following code, but the resulting DataFrame object does not allow analysis. I have attached a sample file (much shortened from the original) below also. Incidentally the first column in the data file is meant to be a date, but in the output is a number corresponding to a day in a si=imulation. Any advice would be much appreciated.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import csv as csv
readdata = csv.reader(open('C:/data/Test.csv', 'r'))
data = []
for row in readdata:
    data.append(row)
a = np.array(data).reshape(11,-1, order = 'F')
col = a[0,:4].reshape(4)
row = pd.Index(a[4:,0:1].reshape(7))
b = a[4:,5:]
df = pd.DataFrame(b, index = row, columns = col)
```

Sample:

```
RN_48865,
1,Observed
1,0
259,Computed
1,0.000014
91,0.000014
182,0.000014
274,0.000014
366,0.000014
457,0.000014
548,0.000014
RN_7445,
1,Observed
1,0
259,Computed
1,0.000013
91,0.000013
182,0.000013
274,0.000013
366,0.000013
457,0.000013
548,0.000013
RN_9288,
1,Observed
1,0
259,Computed
1,0.000011
91,0.000011
182,0.000011
274,0.000011
366,0.000011
457,0.000011
548,0.000011
RN_10955,
1,Observed
1,0
259,Computed
1,0.000014
91,0.000014
182,0.000014
274,0.000014
366,0.000014
457,0.000014
548,0.000014
```

Sample output:

```
Index,RN_48865,RN_7445,RN_9288,RN_10955
1,0.000014,0.000013,0.000011,0.000014
91,0.000014,0.000013,0.000011,0.000014
182,0.000014,0.000013,0.000011,0.000014
274,0.000014,0.000013,0.000011,0.000014
366,0.000014,0.000013,0.000011,0.000014
457,0.000014,0.000013,0.000011,0.000014
548,0.000014,0.000013,0.000011,0.000014
```

Comment: So what is the question?

Comment: Sorry that was not clear. How do I turn the long file into a Dataframe object with an index (of parsed dates that adds the number to a base date, e.g. 1995-1-1; first data column), and multiple columns populated with data from the second column with the "RN_x" labels as the column labels. The original long file has repeated blocks of data representing output at different 'locations' in a sumulation. I want to be able to analyse statistics for each location.

Comment: I don't understand the "multiple columns populated with data from the second column with the "RN_x" labels as the column labels." Why don't you simply show the data (with `\n`s)?

Comment: can I email you the file?

Comment: Maybe it would be clearer if you showed us the desired output, and the exact input including whitespace characters.

Comment: Sample output (desired) added above. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are actually asking several questions. This is what I could understand from the desired output:

```
source="""RN_48865,
    1,Observed
    1,0
    259,Computed
    1,0.000014
    91,0.000014
    182,0.000014
    274,0.000014
    366,0.000014
    457,0.000014
    548,0.000014
    RN_7445,
    1,Observed
    1,0
    259,Computed
    1,0.000013
    91,0.000013
    182,0.000013
    274,0.000013
    366,0.000013
    457,0.000013
    548,0.000013
    RN_9288,
    1,Observed
    1,0
    259,Computed
    1,0.000011
    91,0.000011
    182,0.000011
    274,0.000011
    366,0.000011
    457,0.000011
    548,0.000011
    RN_10955,
    1,Observed
    1,0
    259,Computed
    1,0.000014
    91,0.000014
    182,0.000014
    274,0.000014
    366,0.000014
    457,0.000014
    548,0.000014
"""
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import StringIO
df = pd.read_csv(StringIO.StringIO(source), header=None)
rns = np.where(df[0].apply(lambda x: x.lstrip().startswith('RN_')))[0]
length = rns[1] - rns[0]
index = df[0].iloc[4:length]
cols = df[0][::length].apply(lambda x: x.lstrip()).values
result_df = pd.DataFrame(index=index)
for col_num, col_start in enumerate(range(0, len(df), length)):
    result_df[cols[col_num]] = df[1][col_num*length+4 : (col_num+1)*length].values
print result_df
```

Output:

```
     RN_48865   RN_7445   RN_9288  RN_10955
1    0.000014  0.000013  0.000011  0.000014
91   0.000014  0.000013  0.000011  0.000014
182  0.000014  0.000013  0.000011  0.000014
274  0.000014  0.000013  0.000011  0.000014
366  0.000014  0.000013  0.000011  0.000014
457  0.000014  0.000013  0.000011  0.000014
548  0.000014  0.000013  0.000011  0.000014
```

For dates use:

```
pandas.read_csv('file',
  parse_date=0,  # 0th column
  date_parser=lambda x: pandas.Timestamp('1995-1-1')+timedelta(x))
```

Comment: Thanks that helps with one element. User cyborg pointed out that the question wasnt clear which I agree with.

Comment: Thats great. Thanks very much. Looks like I was on the wrong track there. Still much to learn.